# Unable to connect a TTL to USB converter to a phone

Tags: usb, conversion, serial, phone, ttl

I have been unable to connect the USB side of a **TTL-to-USB** converter to a phone by using a Female-Female USB A adapter and a normal mobile phone cable (which can handle data).

[This is the converter being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTft8.jpg)

The **TTL-to-USB** converter has been successfully tested with the phone in the past by using one of [these connectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BoGL.jpg).

[This is the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqRBX.png) of what I am trying to achieve however for some reason with this setup, it does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the phone using a Type-C or micro-B connector?

Comment: @grawity it is a USB micro B but will need to work with a type C in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB is not an equal peer-to-peer connection; it was designed with one device acting as the "host" (supplying power, assigning addresses, etc.) Normally the type-A connector always goes into the host and type-B connector goes into the "slave" device.

USB micro-B connectors have [an additional pin](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/why-does-micro-usb-2-0-have-5-pins-when-the-a-type-only-has-4) indicating OTG (host) mode vs regular (device) mode. Actual "USB On-The-Go" adapters have this pin grounded, indicating to the phone that it needs to reverse the port's operation (switch to USB host mode and provide power, as opposed to receiving power).

[image: Schematic stolen from the aforelinked Electronics.SE thread]

Your "normal" cable does not connect this pin, because after all it was made to be used in normal mode (with the type-A end going into the USB host instead). So the connection has no device acting as the host.

The female-female type-A adapter cannot do this on its own, because type-A connectors predate USB OTG and do not have this pin (i.e. it doesn't even go all the way through the cable, it just loops back inside the type-B connector).

(Type-C is even more complex, I don't know anything about how it decides between modes.)

Comment: Aha. Thank you ever so much. I was checking the female-female usb A adapter for continuity as I thought that was the problem and when I was checking I realised the extra pin.

Comment: I didn't realise that extra pin needed to be grounded. Thank you for your help. 